# PHPDoc preconditions

Tags: phpdoc, preconditions

How to tag preconditions with PHPDoc? I have an object, and before calling a function another function must have been called:

```
$myObject = new MyClass();
$myObject->mustDoThis();
$myObject->beforeThis();
```

So the documentation for `beforeThis()` would look like:

```
/**
 * @precondition mustDoThis() must be called before this function is
 */
```

Or is there another way around this? Perhaps a `@throw` clause would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no standard @precondition or @postcondition tags for PhpDoc but I use them anyway as it is a nice way to hint the developer implementing the class/interface/trait.

Comment: `@see` is probably the best "standard" way for each method to link to the other.  The description portion of the tag would then describe what their relationship is.

Answer (score 0):

According to the book "Clean Code" written by Robert C. Martin, the scenario you have described is a temporally coupled pair and you should solve it by making a new method which calls those methods in the right order.

The client shouldn't know in which order should call methods so encapsulate the logic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).